# How to handle empty socket buffer

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, exception, network-programming

I am writing a socket server and I noticed that if it received an empty socket buffer, it will cause a socketexception. In the receive call, how can I detect and handle the empty buffer and send a -1 response back to the client before the socket closes?

Code:

```
try
{
    byte[] byteBuffer = new Byte[1024];
    int size = m_clientSocket.Receive(byteBuffer);
    if (size > 0)
    {
        ParseReceiveBuffer(byteBuffer, size);
    }
    else
    {
        m_clientSocket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(-1));
    }
}
catch (SocketException ex)
{
    if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
    {
        // socket buffer is probably empty, wait and try again
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    // connection was unexpectively closed
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. I'd only expect `Receive` to return 0 when the other end had shut down the socket anyway. What *exactly* do you mean by "if it received an empty socket buffer"?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with TCP layer.

Sockets functions like Send and Receive are not actually sending or receiving data over network. They communicate with OS sockets layers to push or pop data from networking layer.
Due to this, when you run from your application method Send, it will put in queue data to send into OS networking layer. Only after that OS will actually send it and might get some issues, so that way it will store error and will throw it straight on next that specific socket method call from your application.

That is why you receive SocketException only on next call when previous might was failed or in between previous and current call network had some error (for example connection lose).

When exception is going to be received you will always receive nothing (zero bytes).
You cannot send anything after exception, due to connection lose (in most (99%) cases).

Client will receive exception as well that will have Error message about connection lose.

Answer (score 0):

using DataAvailable clause in appropriate use.
i recommend you write complete class and helper methods for doing all of these regular.
and thread.sleep(1000) is not necessary since listener will wait for your command line to be executed.
another approach is using developed socket library that you can easily simulate both server and client roles.i know supersocket with that you can customize and develop your own protocol.